# Centering Content in DIV within HTML

Tags: css, html

This is a common request. However, I'm going out of my mind.

```
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body { height: 100%; margin:0px; padding:0px; }
        #content { margin-left: 50%; margin-right: 50%; width:900px; }
    </style>
```

...

```
<body style="min-height:100%; height:100%; position:relative;">
  <header style="min-height:200px;">
      <div style="height:50px; background:url(http://www.mydomain.com/images/bg.gif) repeat-x;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="height:300px; background:url(http://www.mydomain.com/images/bg2.jpg) repeat;">
        <div class="content" style="height:300px; background:url(http://www.mydomain.com/images/masthead-back.jpg) no-repeat;">
          <img alt="Hello" src="http://www.mydomain.com/images/logo.png" />
          Welcome.
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="nav">
        <ul class="navs">
          <li><a href="Main.aspx">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="ContactUs.aspx">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="AboutUs.aspx">About Us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <article class="content" style="padding-bottom:60px;">
    This is the main content
  </article>

  <footer style="position:absolute; bottom:0px; width:100%; height:60px; background-color:black;">
    <div class="content">
      <a href='#'>Privacy</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href='#'>Terms of use</a>
     </div>
  </footer>
</body>
```

I want my header, artcle, and footer items to be centered within the body. But, I want the content within the header, article, and footer to be left-aligned. What am I doing wrong, everything is currently just left-aligned. However, its not centered within the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a wrapper DIV with this CSS:

```
#wrapper { width:800px; margin: 0 auto; }
```

[**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Qjvgs/1/)

Answer (score 0):

you need to set article, header, and footer display style to block in your css to accomodate older browsers

also why not use <nav/> instead of <div id="nav">?

```
article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,
footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section {  display:block; }

 <nav>
        <ul class="navs">
          <li><a href="Main.aspx">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="ContactUs.aspx">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="AboutUs.aspx">About Us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
div.content //or nav or just plain div
{
margin-left: auto; //centers the DIVs
margin-right:auto;
text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add in body

```
width:960px; margin: 0 auto;
```